# Why are `args` not an instance of Rake::TaskArguments when a task is run with `execute` instead of `invoke`?

Tags: ruby, rake

In Rake, when you run a task explicitly from another task using the `execute` command, ie:

```
Rake::Task['some_task'].execute(args=[arg1, arg2])
```

Inside the task that is run, the `args` will be a regular Array. If you run a task with the `invoke` function, ie:

```
Rake::Task['some_task'].invoke(arg1, arg2)
```

The `args` command will be an instance of `Rake::TaskArguments`. As such, you can use methods like `Rake::TaskArguments.with_defaults`.

Why does this difference exist? Is there a way to ensure that the args inside a task will be an instance of `Rake::TaskArguments`?

Generally, it seems odd that the method of calling a tasks changes the identity of the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question and I can't find a stated reason why `invoke` wraps arguments as `Rake::TaskArguments` and `execute` doesn't.

`execute` is called from `invoke` in order to do the work of the task and at that point the arguments are already wrapped up into a `Rake::TaskArguments` instance. That's why in "normal" usage you get a `Rake::TaskArguments` within your task. I'd say normal usage is with tasks specified on the command line or as dependencies. In these cases you'd have the tasks being called via `invoke` within rake itself.

To ensure that the arguments in the task are always a `Rake::TaskArguments` instance I guess the only way is to wrap the arguments when you're using `execute` in your own code. E.g.

```
Rake::Task['some_task'].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new(argument_names, [arg1, arg2]))
```

`argument_names` is required and is the names of the arguments the task expects. You can actually get that from the task itself `Rake::Task['some_task'].arg_names`. The argument position in the name array needs to match the position in the value for named arguments.

Might be worth raising your question as an issue with the rake team : https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues